# How to implement PersistenceQuery of ReadJournalFor in Akka.Net Hosting Model

Tags: akka.net

I've worked through the documentation on Akka.Net PersistenceQuery [here](https://getakka.net/articles/persistence/persistence-query.html), but I'm struggling to figure out how I would hook up any of those queries inside an ASP.Net6 Blazor Server startup pipeline using the new Akka.Net [Hosting model](https://petabridge.com/blog/intro-akka-hosting/).

What I have in mind is to Sink such a query out to a SignalR hub that will cause views to refresh their data based on the output of a  `ReadForJournal` stream.

Has anyone done this, and if so, please can you provide me with some guidance in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this before, much less an expert are this, but I can try to point you in the right direction! :)

If you want to run a local actor, you can spawn the `ProjectionBehavior` as any other `Behavior`. This can be useful for testing or when running a local `ActorSystem` without Akka Cluster.

```js
SourceProvider<Offset, EventEnvelope<ShoppingCart.Event>> sourceProvider(String tag) {
  return EventSourcedProvider.eventsByTag(system, CassandraReadJournal.Identifier(), tag);
}

Projection<EventEnvelope<ShoppingCart.Event>> projection(String tag) {
  return CassandraProjection.atLeastOnce(
      ProjectionId.of("shopping-carts", tag), sourceProvider(tag), ShoppingCartHandler::new);
}

Projection<EventEnvelope<ShoppingCart.Event>> projection1 = projection("carts-1");

ActorRef<ProjectionBehavior.Command> projection1Ref =
    context.spawn(ProjectionBehavior.create(projection1), projection1.projectionId().id());
```

You can combine this with your predefined query, e.g.:

```js
var queries = PersistenceQuery.Get(actorSystem)
    .ReadJournalFor<SqlReadJournal>("akka.persistence.query.my-read-journal");

var mat = ActorMaterializer.Create(actorSystem);
Source<string, NotUsed> src = queries.AllPersistenceIds();
```

So I was thinking maybe your `queries` could be linked to your `ProjectionBehavior` for the akka hosting model to host it.

Related sources:

- [Getakka.net persistence-query](https://getakka.net/articles/persistence/persistence-query.html)
- [Akka projection dox](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-projection/current/running.html)
- [Akka hosting](https://petabridge.com/blog/intro-akka-hosting/)

Comment: Thanks, but I have already been through all the referenced documentation, and still required actual implementation guidance, prompting this question.  I'll award the bounty to an answer that shows a working example.

Comment: Oh, my bad! I'll try to change my answer! @ShawndeWet

Comment: Have you read all 3 links? Your qns only has 2 @ShawndeWet